# Fedora 25 GNU/Linux - find missing disk space and resize LVM

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, fedora, lvm

I've installed Fedora Server 25 64-bit using LVM and automatic disk partitioning.
Automatically created /root volume was too small (16 GB) and a lot of free space was left and still available on the disk.
The disk is an Intel SSD 180 GB SATA drive.
So I've resized /root with the "lvextend" and "pvresize" by allocating 100% of the free space to it under a live CD system.
Something went wrong because the /root volume is resized (it now has about 170 GB), but it's still 98% full.
Please check the output of "fdisk -l" and "df -h" commands:

```
[igor@uc-srv ~]$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.9G  256K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    3.9G  1.6M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   15G   15G  406M  98% /
tmpfs                    3.9G   32K  3.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                976M  138M  772M  16% /boot
/dev/sdb1                341G   52G  289G  16% /media/ntfs1
tmpfs                    793M   16K  793M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                    793M   16K  793M   1% /run/user/1000

[igor@uc-srv ~]$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 167.7 GiB, 180045766656 bytes, 351651888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc0948dd2

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   2099199   2097152     1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       2099200 351651839 349552640 166.7G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdb: 372.6 GiB, 400088457216 bytes, 781422768 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc0c96c56

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         2048 714313727 714311680 340.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       714313728 781420543  67106816    32G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 158.8 GiB, 170515234816 bytes, 333037568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 7.9 GiB, 8451522560 bytes, 16506880 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

As you can see, df says that fedora-root is 15 GB, fdisk says it's 158 GB.
What should I do to recover the free space and assign it properly to /root ?

UPDATE: When I run:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/fedora-root
```

I get:

```
resize2fs 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/fedora-root
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Comment: What commands did you run exactly? When you ran `lvextend`, did you use `-r` (or `--resizefs`)?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not 100% sure about the commands I've used. I think the first one was: "lvextend -L+100%FREE /dev/fedora/root" and the second was: "pvresize -v /dev/sda2" or "lvresize -r -l+100%FREE fedora/root" :-(

Comment: What does `lvscan` show?

Comment: ACTIVE            '/dev/fedora/swap' [7.87 GiB] inherit  
  ACTIVE            '/dev/fedora/root' [158.80 GiB] inherit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you ran `lvextend` without giving the `-r` (or `--resizefs`) option. That means you extended the volume, but the filesystem on top of that — or inside it, if you prefer — stayed the same. It's like a bunch of Russian nesting dolls.

Fortunately, you can do that now. Run

```
sudo xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/fedora-root
```

and that will grow that partition to fill the maximum available size. (You can grow like this while the system is running.) Note that this is for the Fedora Server default filesystem, XFS. Other Fedora variants still use EXT4 by default; for those, replace `xfs_growfs` with `resize2fs`. Both have the same default behavior of growing the filesystem to fill available space, which in this case will be the rest of the logical volume.

This is relatively risk-free (it's probably been done millions of times with no incident), but like all major filesystem operations, it's a good idea to have backups of any important data first.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so much, you saved me! :-) How did you learned Linux?

Comment: @Marek Practice :)

Comment: Also of note, XFS CAN NOT BE actively shrunk only grown.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. This is one reason to not allocate everything at once — instead, leave free space and add it to filesystems as needed.